# show row contents in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, oracle10g

my problem is when I add account the account successfully added, but the row content is not showing in my datagridview.
this is the code for my add button in addaccount form. "frmaddaccount is the name of the form and button1 is the button when i add.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim un = TextBox1.Text
        Dim pw = TextBox2.Text
        Dim ac = lbluser.Text
        Dim fn = TextBox4.Text
        Dim ln = TextBox5.Text
        Dim age = TextBox6.Text
        Dim val = "accountId_seq.nextval,'" & un & "','" & pw & "','" & ac & "','" & fn & "','" & ln & "','" & age & "'"
        Dim sql = "insert into d_account values(" & val & ")"
        con.Connect()
        con.Manipulate(sql)
        accountLog()
        MessageBox.Show("Account successfulyy added!")
        display()
        con.Close()
        clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR:" & vbCrLf & " " & vbCrLf & " 1. Complete the required information " & vbCrLf & " 2. Make sure that you input correct datatypes " & vbCrLf & " 3. Username already exist")
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub frmaddAccount_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.Connect()
    datagridview1.DataSource = dtb
    dtb.Columns.Add("Username")
    dtb.Columns.Add("Password")
    dtb.Columns.Add("Access")
    dtb.Columns.Add("First Name")
    dtb.Columns.Add("Last Name")
    dtb.Columns.Add("Age")
    display()
    con.Close()
End Sub
Sub display()
    con.Connect()
    Dim sql = "select * from d_account order by d_un asc"
    odr = con.Retrieve(sql)
    dtb.Clear()
    While (odr.Read)
        Dim un = odr.GetOracleValue(1)
        Dim pw = odr.GetOracleValue(2)
        Dim ac = odr.GetOracleValue(3)
        Dim fn = odr.GetOracleValue(4)
        Dim ln = odr.GetOracleValue(5)
        Dim age = odr.GetOracleValue(6)

        dtb.Rows.Add(un, pw, ac, fn, ln, age)
    End While
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

and this is the code in manageaccount form where my datagridview place.. frmmanageaccount is the name of the form.

```
  Private Sub frmmanageAccount_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.Connect()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dtb
    dtb.Columns.Add("Account ID")
    dtb.Columns.Add("Username")
    dtb.Columns.Add("Password")
    dtb.Columns.Add("Access")
    dtb.Columns.Add("First Name")
    dtb.Columns.Add("Last Name")
    dtb.Columns.Add("Age")
    display()

    con.Close()
    Label14.Text = DataGridView1.RowCount()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(i).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic
    Next
    Me.DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("CAmbria", 10)
    Me.DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("CAmbria", 12)
    Me.DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromArgb(129, 207, 224)
    End Sub
Sub display()
    con.Connect()
    Dim sql = "select * from d_account where d_ac = 'user' order by d_un asc"
    odr = con.Retrieve(sql)
    dtb.Clear()
    While (odr.Read)
        Dim id = odr.GetOracleValue(0)
        Dim un = odr.GetOracleValue(1)
        Dim pw = odr.GetOracleValue(2)
        Dim ac = odr.GetOracleValue(3)
        Dim fn = odr.GetOracleValue(4)
        Dim ln = odr.GetOracleValue(5)
        Dim age = odr.GetOracleValue(6)

        dtb.Rows.Add(id, un, pw, ac, fn, ln, age)
        Label14.Text = DataGridView1.RowCount()
    End While
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Couple of things. You only need to open the connection when you're going to do something on the database. You seem to be opening it in a few places that aren't needed. Same with closing. Looking into implementing `Using` for these objects so they are disposed of correctly.  Next use parameters. This will help with reducing syntax issues and stop SQL injection. You don't need to add rows like that to a `DataGridView`. Instead assign the reader to the `.DataSource` property. Also you are swallowing the exceptions so never really know what has gone wrong.

Comment: @bugs can you help me to fix this code?